# How can I implement the uncurry function on python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying, arity

I have function curry with arbitrary arity:

```
def curry_explicit(function, arity):
    if arity == 0:
        return function
    def get_args(args):
        if len(args) == arity:
            return function(*args)

        def curry(x):
            return get_args([*args, x])

        return curry

    return get_args([])
```

How can I make a uncurry function that will take the curried function and arity as input?

Need a similar result:

```
f = curry_explicit(max, 3)
g = uncurry_explicit(f, 3)

print(f(3)(6)(9))
print(g(3, 6, 12))
```

```
9
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient way and omitting error checks:

```
def curry_explicit(function, arity):
    if arity == 0:
        return function
    def get_args(args):
        if len(args) == arity:
            return function(*args)

        def curry(x):
            return get_args([*args, x])

        return curry

    return get_args([])
    
def uncurry_explicit(f):
    def uncurry(*args):
        result = f
        
        for a in args:
            result = result(a)
        
        return result
        
    return uncurry
    
f = curry_explicit(max, 3)
g = uncurry_explicit(f)

print(f(3)(6)(9))
print(g(3, 6, 12))
```

This solution doesn't need the arity for uncurrying.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of [Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283563/12671057):

```py
from functools import reduce   
from operator import call

def uncurry_explicit(f):
    return lambda *args: reduce(call, args, f)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLLSsQwFMVtvuIuc6WCWhh0oF8iMsQ2qYE0KXdSaL_FzWz0o_wUV-bVjoyTRUjOPefcQ3I_vsbFvzt7On1OXt09fd_8dFJBOxEtBzmPRrfaczXZ1mtnKxCk_YJ7BmFpla_QNHCfobhI-oksrJqER89e-oOg_sjjhmd-sDHSZjRaJc9z-Yolv01ktnG2yHzGq8qt90uSVjC__pEXUnLI6D9ZoANT5IYcwjlzBD2MjnzgdlMrgyjX3ShJeEdruRXGMBYTBuHFs5awpZsRw1snICXcF1se5fHZY2iFic4UNJc_NIi5ghpZH0pX-jA2krbhxGvkO-TPiAXpeV3BroKHR8Q8AmUS1on4BQ)